# White lines appear right in the middle of my Dell XPS M1210 screen

Tags: lcd, laptop-repair, dell-xps

My Dell XPSM1210 has developed these weird lines right in the middle of the screen. When I connect an external monitor the lines disappear and the display is fine.

Is this a problem with the screen panel, and if it needs replacement is there a place where I could buy one?

This laptop is not under warranty so I'm willing to get the screen replaced.

[image: Dell XPS M1210 white lines in the middle of the screen]

Comment: I've also tried to use screen capture and the lines don't show in the capture. It definitely is a hardware problem but I'd like to know if I can find the exact component that's faulty! Thanks.

Comment: When you say: "When I connect an external monitor the lines disappear and the display is fine", do you mean the laptop screen is fine?

Comment: I'm sorry, no, I mean that I see no lines on the external monitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be one of 4 things, of the top of my head.

1. The ribbon cable connecting to your laptop screen.
   Solution: Fixable by going to one of those computer repair shops that also deal in laptops. Of course, you can also go to a Dell representative in your general area. But may be a bit more expensive
2. The screen itself.
   Solution: Probably needs to be replaced. Quite annoyingly so because it's always more expensive. Computer repair shops or Dell.
3. More rarely, the inverter board.
   I find it odd the lines are white. So why I thought of this one.
   Solution: Needs to be replaced. Cheaper than the above two.
4. Bad soldering or dislodged cable.
   Solution: The cheapest, eh. No replacement parts. Just putting things back in place.